# openmp parallel for - How does it handle previously private index?

Tags: c, openmp

I have a parallel block containing 2 parallel for-loops:

```
    int i, j;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
      #pragma omp for
      for(i=0; i < foo; i++)
        work();


      #pragma omp for private(j)
      for(i=0; i < foo; i++)
        for(j=0, j < foo; j++)
          work();
    }
```

If I were to make it private like this:

```
int i, j;
    #pragma omp parallel private(i)
    {
      #pragma omp for
      for(i=0; i < foo; i++)
        work();


      #pragma omp for private(j)
      for(i=0; i < foo; i++)
        for(j=0, j < foo; j++)
          work();
    }
```

Then I have NUM_THREADS amount of i copies. Will openMP still be able to schedule my threads based on i in parallel for loops and how? If I don't make it private that way (see first code example) then what behaviour can I expect from i between the two for-loops?

It is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845291/openmp-outer-loop-private-or-shared) because I know you can usually let the parralel loop implicitly create a private version of i but I am more concerned about whether that works as expected with a variable that has been private before or has even been worked on before while being temporarily private.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenMP outer loop private or shared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845291/openmp-outer-loop-private-or-shared)

Comment: @Zulan, it's not exactly a duplicate. There is a subtle difference in that in the first code example `i` is only private in the work sharing region otherwise it's still shared inside the parallel region.  The same goes for `j` in both examples. That's not a problem with the current code but it could create problems if the code relied on the value of `i` or `j` after the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question

> what behaviour can I expect from i between the two for-loops?

In your first example `i` is only private in the work sharing region (in the for loops). Between the two work sharing regions it's still shared.  In the second example since you declared `i` private for the parallel region it's private everywhere.

The is easy to show.

```
i = 1;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for(i=0; i<10; i++);
    i = 10;
}
printf("%d\n", i);
```

This prints `10` because `i` is shared except in the work sharing region and every thread writes `10` to the shared `i`.

However,

```
i = 1;
#pragma omp parallel private(i)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for(i=0; i<10; i++);
    i = 10;
}
printf("%d\n", i);
```

prints `1` because `i` is private in the entire parallel region and does not modify the `i` outside of the parallel region.

In your current code since you only use `i` in the work sharing region then it makes no difference but if used `i` not in a work sharing region between the loops it could make a difference.  This could lead to a subtle bug. Since you only use `i` in the work sharing region then I would suggest declaring `i` in the work sharing region using `for(int i=0; ...` or declare it private for the whole region.  The same goes for `j`.

Comment: Thank you. That example helped me understand how private and shared work in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You second for-loop will not compile unless you change your code as

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  #pragma omp for
  for(i=0; i < foo; i++)
    work();

  #pragma omp for private(j)
  for(i=0; i < foo; i++)
    for(j=0, j < foo; j++)
      work();
}
```

and

```
int i, j;
#pragma omp parallel private(i)
{
  #pragma omp for
  for(i=0; i < foo; i++)
    do();

  #pragma omp for private(j)
  for(i=0; i < foo; i++)
    for(j=0, j < foo; j++)
      work();
}
```

It is now clear what scope the private `i` is.

---

After the modification, all of the 4 for-loops will work as expected.

> Will openMP still be able to schedule my threads based on i in parallel for loops and how?

Yes, at each `#pragma omp for`, the private `i`s will be initialized properly and used in the parallel for.

> If I don't make it private that way (see first code example) then what behavior can I expect from `i` between the two for-loops?

The index in parallel for defined by `#pragma omp for` will always be private even if you declare it as shared. So your first code example still work.

Actually it doesn't matter whether you declare `i` as private or not according to this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845938/1957265

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of the curly brackets. This doesn't really answer my question though.

Comment: @Escadin all your 4 for-loops will work as expected.

Comment: There is a difference. If you declare `i` private for the parallel region then it's private for the entire parallel region. Otherwise it's only private for the work sharing region.

Comment: @zboson you are right. but there's no code in the region that i is different. Maybe we need to change the question a little.

Comment: Well you could answer the OPs last sentence and question "what behavior can I expect from i between the two for-loops?"  It should be to show that it makes a difference if `i` is private or shared between the loops.

Comment: Regarding my first question:  I guess it's easier for me to imagine if I remind myself that openMP can schedule the team properly based on a private variable nomatter how it became private. The equivalent would be declaring i in the parallel loop itself which would obsviously work.