# what is the effect of private(i,j) in this code? will there be any change if i omit i or j from private(i,j)?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

this is a program to transpose a matrix in openmp c, compiler i used is gcc.
i tried both private(i,j) and private(i) separately. since it is threaded, i couldnt find what change exactly occurs.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private (i,j)
    for(i=1; i<size; i++)
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(j=0; j<i; j++) 
        {
        temp = mat1[i][j];
            mat1[i][j] = mat1[j][i];
            mat1[j][i] = temp;
        }   
}
```

runtime is different everytime. i tried this with 5 threads even though i have a dual core. thank you.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/37845291/620382

Comment: I'd be more worried about the private / shared attribute of `temp`.

Comment: Have you set OMP_NESTED? If not, then the inner parallel is elided (this is probably what you want :-)), if you have, then you likely have even more over-subscription than you asked for! (starting 25 threads). You;d be much better off adopting a style in which you declare variables in the smallest scope possible. Then you wouldn't have to worry about private here.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the effect of private(i,j) in this code?

None.

> will there be any change if i omit i or j from private(i,j)?

No, because OpenMP specifies that

> The loop iteration variable(s) in the associated *for-loop(s)* of a `for`, `parallel for`, `taskloop`, or `distribute` construct is (are) private.

You do not need to explicitly declare the iteration variables private, and doing so changes nothing.  Generally, you must not declare data-sharing attributes for variables that have *pre-determined* data sharing properties, but OpenMP makes a special exception for certain cases of redundant attribute declarations, including this one.